# A direct product $G=\mathbb{Z}_4\times\mathbb{Z}_4\times\mathbb{Z}_4\times\mathbb{Z}_4$ of the cyclic group $\mathbb{Z}_4$ of order $4$.

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory, cyclic-groups, direct-product

Let $G=\mathbb{Z}_4\times\mathbb{Z}_4\times\mathbb{Z}_4\times\mathbb{Z}_4=\mathbb{Z}_4^4$ be a direct product of $4$ copies of the the cyclic group $\mathbb{Z}_4$ of order $4$. Can one regards $G$ as a vector space of dimension $4$ over the ring $\mathbb{Z}_4$ or can it only be regarded as a $4$-dimensional module over $\mathbb{Z}_4$?

Comment: $\Bbb{Z}_4$ is not a field, so $G$ can not be a vector space.

Comment: The very phrase "vector space over BLAH" implies that BLAH is a field.

Comment: @Zerox One can rectify what the OP says into "$\mathbb Z^4$ is a **module** over the **ring** $\mathbb Z".$

Comment: I hope you know that most modules don't have a basis or dimension. But specifically the module you have defined is free, and so we can say it has dimension $4$ over $\mathbb{Z_4}$. As it was already noted, this is not a vector space. A vector space is a module over a field.